# ScriptIgnore on metadata

Tags: c#, json, serialization, data-annotations

I am using JavaScriptSerializer to serialize EF4 Entities, and getting circular reference while trying to serializing them to JSON.

I do no want to edit the generated models so I supplied a metadata class, and marked those properties as ScriptIgnore, but I guess JavaScriptSerializer does not utilise the metadata, because I am still getting the same error.

So how do you, would you, serialize your objects to json in this case. Is there a way of doing this without using ViewModels and probably with the default JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: looks like there is a JavaScriptTypeResolver class, that could probably be used to utilize the metadata class?, any ideas about this?

Answer (score 3):

By adding a `JavaScriptConverter` [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151913/some-questions-regarding-javascriptserializer/4151936#4151936). Note that we don't need any special access to the entities being serialized to do this, but it might be a huge pain if you have lots of entities that are affected by this issue. If that is a likely problem, it will probably be less work to just write a DTO class (that twins with your model) that you can control more directly.

You are right not to edit the generated classes, and (frustratingly) you can't use a `partial class` to add attributes to members declared in another part of the `partial class`.

Comment: If I were using POCOs instead of generated entity models, would this still be a problem? What do you think?

Comment: @hazimdikenli in that case you would have full control over the model to tweak it. This is indeed *in part* what I meant by creating a DTO layer.